# How should I create a web interface for my application?

Tags: javascript, python, css

**First, a little background**: I have written a little application in python with SQLAlchemy, which is roughly an improved RSS reader: it selects links that should interest the user, and shows them to him. I already have a very simple command-line interface, and I envision a variety of interfaces: web, instant-messaging, desktop...

For now **I'd like to create a simple web interface**, but I have absolutely zero experience in the matter (appart from making a simple php forum 5 or 6 years ago...). So I'm comming here for advice on where to start:

1. Is there a good tutorial on HTML/CSS/Javascript focused on making a website look good simply? I know about w3schools, but it's a terrible tutorial IMHO, since it teaches you about HTML/CSS but doesn't show you *how* to use them.
2. Should I use a javascript library? Which one?
3. Should I use a web framework? I'm guessing either not or a very lightweight one, since I already have an application core with a database and SQLAlchemy, and I don't want to drop it.
4. Any other advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Edit: note that I'm not a beginner in programming, just in making web interfaces.

Comment: Some more precisions: the code is not "legacy" code, it's multipurpose code and the web interface is only one of many.

Also, the web interface will primarily be a "desktop" web application, meaning the server will run on the user's machine (see oneswarm for an example of this).

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your very valuable input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like everyone else here, I'll chime in with "Use my favorite framework, because it's what I use...."

I would start with small goals for a web interface. Get something simple up and running that to make sure you understand how things work.

Write an app that responds to the following url and returns something.

http://localhost:8000/my_links

Once you understand the little bit of machinery it takes to make that possible, what is handed to you as far as information about the request, and what you need to produce to return to the caller, it should be come clear how to fill in the blanks to get from your existing application to data thrown at the web browser.

[Learn WSGI](http://wsgi.org/wsgi/Learn_WSGI) for no other reason than most of the libraries that will help you build a web application utilize this to some degree.

One of the links from the above page that I found extremely beneficial in understanding how all this works. was Ian Bickings article "[A Do-it Yourself Framework](http://pythonpaste.org/do-it-yourself-framework.html)"

Once you get a grasp of that stuff, you may find that dealing with WSGI at such a low level is maybe a little too cumbersome. That's when you'll probably want something like [WebOb](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/)
 which is just one of several ways people have come up with for abstracting away the low level details of the request/response cycle into some convenient objects. In a sense encompassing the HTTP protocol without trying to make it make sense to someone who doesn't want to know what HTTP is.

Depending on the complexity of your application you may decide that handling a request, looking at the path and dispatching off to one of many functions is a drag you'd rather not deal with. This is where everyone's favorite framework starts to be beneficial. And I would suspect that you would know enough by this point to better assess the frameworks that are out there and determine which fits your needs and goals.

Lots prefer django, maybe you will too. Others prefer Turbogears, and or Pylons, maybe bfg, maybe grok, maybe zope, maybe plone. But no one here knows what you want your application to do.

Comment: So basically you tell the OP to reinvent the wheel, before choosing one of the solutions you have just voted down? Such a bottom-up approach looks a bit daunting and not necessary at all.

Comment: And did you vote it down yet? It's an option, and one that would leave the OP better informed and able to innovate regardless of what framework they end up using. Everything is daunting until you actually do it. Had the OP said, "I need to get this done today..." My answer would be different. I sincerely apologize if you lose any sleep over my humble opinionated -1 . It's based on my experience using a variety of frameworks that got in the way more than they helped.

Comment: I didn't, you are providing another point of view that may be useful - and indeed it was, congrats! :). Anyway, no sleep lost at all, I just disagree with voting down based on wrong critera but that's probably more a problem of interpreting the votes that would have belonged to Meta.

Comment: thanks, we may just disagree on the definition of mis-information. but  my voting policy is based on the faq section "be honest" 

Be honest.

"Above all, be honest. If you see misinformation, vote it down. Insert comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong. Even better — edit and improve the information! Provide stronger, faster, superior answers of your own!"

Answer (score 6):

I recommend that you use some kind of web framework, it will make things a lot easier. Since you already know Python you should look into [Django framework.](http://www.djangoproject.com/) It seems that you can use SQLAlchemy with Django, see [djange-sqlalchemy project.](http://code.google.com/p/django-sqlalchemy/)

I recommend using [JQuery framework/library](http://jquery.com/) for Javascript stuff. It greatly simplifies coding and takes care of most web browser incompabilities.

This CSS [tutorial](http://www.csstutorial.net/css_tutorial_part1.php) seems to give you the basics.

I would start by reading the [Django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#intro-tutorial01) and start trying things out. I wouldn't worry too much about HTML stuff, you should be able to pick up enough from Django tutorial. Make your site first functional with HTML, Django and SQLAlchemy. Only then start worring about Javascript. Who knows, maybe you do not need Javascript at all?

Do not try make your site work and look good at the same time. When you are making your site work, use simple and ugly HTML pages. When you are making you web site look good, work only with static HTML pages and CSS files. It is easier to combine the two in the end.

Comment: +1 but before even picking up a framework, you should always learn to make some stuff from scratch in Python, and above all, in xHTML / CSS.

Comment: -1 if the OP already has an application written with sqlalchemy implying an existing db, django would probably hurt rather than help. Avoiding django's orm is the exception to the norm.

Comment: @Tom: Like for my post, this -1 is uncalled for. There _is_ a way to integrate both, and the OP is looking at a way to extend their application. Both Django or web2py are valid solutions with a minimum or no change.

Comment: @redglyph I don't agree. there is a way, but it is the exception to the norm. and thus I feel it's not good advice. I believe the consensus with django is that a lot of the benefits of it come from tight integration with their own orm.which is fine, but it has drawbacks which are not mentioned in the above answer.

Comment: @Tom: If you feel you have to add a piece of information, just post a comment. Voting Juha's solution means it's not useful, which is not true. In this case, against the potential disadvantage, the OP would gain support in a solid framework. Besides, other information is given in answer to the CSS tutorial and Javascript questions. You should think your voting policy over IMHO :-)

Comment: @redglyph: opinions are what makes the internet great.

Answer (score 3):

It's an interestingly common mistake: all of the above answers provide technological advise on what's the best technology to do ... what exactly? You should work the other way around.

I think that if you want your application to be successful, you have to make sure it enables its users to get the most out of it in the most natural way to them.

Therefore, i suggest you first "storyline" how things should happen from a user's perspective. Use paper and pen, or more sophisticated wireframing tools such as [balsamiq mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups).

So, first lay out what the experience should be, and this will tell you which technology will be the best choice to enable that experience.

Oh, and don't forget to read [this](http://www.userfocus.co.uk/resources/taskchecklist.html).

Answer (score 1):

HTML, CSS and JS Book: [DHTML and CSS for the World Wide Web](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201730847)

Javascript Library: JQuery

Web Framework: Not sure, DJango?

Other Advice: Learn to write HTML, CSS, and JS in a a simple text editor with syntax highlighting. Complex IDE's are cool, but for this stuff, they will make you learn slower.

Answer (score 1):

Web applications are not simple.

HTML and CSS: [Head First HTML](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101978/) is probably a good starting point. The Head First series are usually excellent tutorials. As Josh said, write your pages by hand.

Javascript: you don't need this to get started. Maybe in a later version. When you have a better idea what you'll need Javascript for, you'll be better equipped to pick a library that suits your needs.

Web framework: You should probably start with [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/). That's the opposite of a "very lightweight" framework, but in this context "lightweight" requires more expertise to make something polished. So it's a good idea to aim for "feature rich and well supported" instead.

Comment: Ok, I fully agree with you on almost everything, however, you can't say that django is "the opposite of lightweight". I mean, ok, the feature set of django might (or might not) be considered huge, but it doesn't force you into any particular way of thinking/coding. You can just use the url dispatcher for convenience and template engine to format html and that's it. And that will save you a whole lot of typing and/or trouble.

Comment: The intent of Django is to be a full-stack framework (dispatch, ORM, templates, etc.). That sets it in a different category from lightweight "frameworks" such as Cherrypy or Pylons. That it is possible with enough effort no to use Django as a full-stack framework is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option, I feel it's worth mentioning before making any decision.

As web framework I would advise [web2py](http://www.web2py.com), it is very easy to setup and yet powerful. [Here is a document](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.web2py.com%2Fexamples%2Fstatic%2Fweb2py_vs_others.pdf&rct=j&q=web2py_vs_others.pdf&ei=yQgAS8KlJ86w4QbS6_D2Cw&usg=AFQjCNE_fglzZ-buu-5g5gtoGen6TFiPug) showing the differences between Django, web2py and some others. It is somewhat old but will give you a good overview.

Since you have legacy code, if you really want to keep it there is a [fair compatibility between the two](http://mdp.cti.depaul.edu/AlterEgo/default/show/189) although you should double-check. The easiest would be [to adapt your code](http://www.web2py.com/AlterEgo/default/show/150), of course, the differences aren't so big. But that's your call :-)

Regarding the Javascript library, probably jQuery.

Comment: like the recommendation for django, you are essentially telling the OP to ditch their work and re-do in your preferred framework.

Comment: No, read again: I'm saying there are two alternatives, to keep it like it is, or to _adapt_ the code - there is no mention of "ditching" the code as you say, the modifications would be minor or not necessary at all. It is at this stage of the project that such questions are to be asked, not later: if some adaptations can ensure the support of a framework that makes the rest of the work much easier, don't you think it's worth considering? Do you have an actual solution to propose?

Comment: well, if it were possible to adapt, then why does this page exist to show you essentially how to replace sqlalchemy with whatever web2py does for you?  http://web2py.com/examples/static/sqla2.html

Comment: The link you mention is for people who know SQLAlchemy and want to switch to web2py - it's mentioned in the title - so I'm not sure it's relevant ;-) The second link _I_ provided in my post shows how to adapt code, the first one shows how to use existing code.

Comment: The "to adapt your code" link, and the one I mentioned seem to imply the same thing which looks like "Here's how you do it in sqlalchemy, and here's how you do it in web2py". Is this not the case? The only thing that would be reused is the database schema I imagine. To me that makes your answer in a nutshell "Step one: rewrite everything, but you can keep the tables". According to your link, the OP would be screwed if they used something other than autoincrement id's for primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

The best introduction you could follow is the opera web standards curriculum.  Some of the information will be too basic - but a full understanding of all the topics covered will give you a very good grounding.

http://www.opera.com/company/education/curriculum/

Alternatively team up with someone who specialises in front-end development.